# Can't get CSS3 flex to work in Joomla 2.5

Tags: css, joomla2.5, flexbox

I'm using Joomla 2.5.14 and the beez_20 template as the basis for a website. I been trying to use CSS3 flex on a page but it doesn't seem to work. I checked the HTML and CSS code here:

```
<div id="intro_container">
  <div class="square"></div><p></p>
  <div class="square" ></div><p></p>
</div>

.square { background-color:red; width: 80px; height: 80px; }
#intro_container  { width: 250px; height: 150px;border: 1px solid black;background:lightblue;display: flex;flex-direction: row;justify-content: space-around;  flex-wrap: wrap;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ka01ntk1/4 
But nothing is displayed when I put the code into a Joomla article like so:

```
<div id="intro_page"><a href="/index.php/what-to-do-now"><img id="logo_world_green_arrow" src="/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/logo_world_green_arrow.png" alt="logo_world_green_arrow"   height="125px" width="110px" align="left"  ></a> <div id="intro_text"><p  id="intro_text"><span id="e2tw_title">Introduction</span> <a href="#" class="thai_btn">ไทย</a></p></div>
```

I'm wondering whether HTML5 and CSS3 work in the beez_20 template. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Css part has to be placed at the end of: `/templates/beez_20/css/template.css`. Then adding your code inside the article will show the desired result.

Please try to correct also: `<div id="intro_text"><p  id="intro_text">`.

Css doesn't allow [more than one element with same id in a page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). You could use classes instead like:

`<div class="intro_text"><p  class="intro_text">`.

Good Luck!